# Can symlinks be used to point to a remote file that may not be available

Tags: raspberry-pi, symlink

I'm looking for a smart way to manage a pi I use for downloading with omv5, dockstarter, docker, etc...

My pi can be on all the time, but the larger server I'd like a schedule, so the pi will use  wol to wake it up and send downloaded files if there is an update in a folder.

Question is though, I was thinking symlinks would allow me to fill up a Sonarr/radarr library virtually (without creating a huge database) with the real files on another server. But can the symlinks be cut off from their target every so often and still behave like the target file?

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: "...and still behave like the target file?" What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: Symlinks that point to nonexistent files are named "broken links". Trying to access them generates an error, which is not the same behaviour as symlinks pointing to existing files. Can't the program on the Pi just wait until the server is up? Or you create a directory on the Pi that the server rsync's periodically? Or use NFS?

Comment: The exact issue I'm having is the pi is too small to media serve and manage a whole download server so I'd like the media files to rsync to a server and remain there. But that means that the library will go off periodically and sonarr / radarr won't be able to access the library and will see the media kinda going all over the place. Idea is to copy new folders in and then move them but leave a file that looks like the file even of the main library is offline. Can this be done with rsync? Symlinks or some variation of dynlinks?

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a symlink simply as a text file that contains the path it is pointing to. The target file does not have to exist for this to work.

In fact, there are programs which use symlinks to encode information, where the path being stored in the symlink is never intended to resolve to a file. An example are the Gatling and Fnord web servers, which use symlinks for HTTP redirects:

```sh
mkdir -p /var/www/mysite.example.com:80
cd /var/www/mysite.example.com:80
ln -s 'http://www.google.com:80/search?q=site:mysite.example.com' search.html
```

Means that Fnord will respond to a request for http://mysite.example.com:80/search.html with an HTTP redirect to Google.

So, it is perfectly possible for the target of a symlink to go away.

However, it is not clear what you mean by "still behave like the target file?" A symlink simply contains a path name, and all it does is that when you open the symlink, the OS actually opens the path that is stored inside the symlink instead. So, in some sense, yes, the symlink still behaves like the target file: If you had tried to open the same path without using the symlink, then you would have gotten an error, and with the symlink, you still get an error.

If you are asking about the possibility of having "dynlinks", i.e. symlinks that dynamically point to different paths depending on some sort of variable or condition (similarly to NTFS "reparse points" in Windows NT), those *do* exist in some Unices (see for example [Dragonfly BSD's *variant symlinks*](https://man.dragonflybsd.org/?command=ln)), but they don't exist in POSIX nor in Linux.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. Can dynlinks be set to not throw up an error if the linked file / folder is offline? I'd like the server to sleep and when the pi has a file it does wol, then transfers th le files to server, then leave a file that will make sonarr believe its still there. No media players will be pointed at that "library"

Answer (score 0):

I think one very easy way would be to use `sshfs`-mounts i.e. just mount the server's directories via ssh onto a local directory of the pi. You may then just point any symlinks there:

```
 mkdir /home/pi-user/serverlib
 sshfs user@server:/path/to/lib /home/pi-user/serverlib
 ln -s /home/pi-user/serverlib/programm_library.so.0.2
```

There are several ways for you to ensure that the mount exists as it should you could e.g. (among many other options):

1. Place a dummy file `i_am_unmounted` into the directory. If the network location is mounted, the test `[ -e /home/pi-user/serverlib/i_am_unmounted ]` would fail in a script. (use `-o nonempty` in `sshfs`).
2. Search for the remote directory in the output of `mount`.
3. Be more elaborate and make all a `systemd` service including the WOL, mounting, checking for a successful mount and running the file updates.

Comment: SSHFS is brilliant. I'd use it but trying to find a solution for symlinks or variants of that to solve for a sonarr radarr library that will be going offline periodically. So if sonarr were to manage the false library, that's synced to the server then I should have no issues with it going offline every so often

Comment: @Fredfree I'm not sure if I get you properly, but I understand that you want the `sonarr/radarr` service to only run in case the server mount is active? `systemd` would be able to manage this then. Create a mount (e.g. [systemd sshfs mount](https://gist.github.com/proprietary/96f6f08758fb98da8467880904191f64) but replace `WantedBy` with the `radarr`-service) and then adapt the `radarr` service to depend on the mount.